# DateDiff sql Activerecord

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Нужно выводить запись, только после того как прошло 20 минут,
есть такой код, но он не работает. дата хранится в int в unixtimestamp

```
$query->andWhere("DATEDIFF(minute, NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(`created_at`,'%Y %m %d %H:%i:%s')) >= 20");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE `created_at` <= NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE
```